# How to get the Ansible playbook run failure information

Tags: shell, ansible

I have been executing the Ansible playbooks. In general, if the playbook runs successfully it would return "0". But currently in my environment, there is no return code or any error message on Ansible console even though the playbook execution is failed. This playbook should executed with in 2-3 minutes of time and same observed in test environments.

Problem: in our current production environment it is taking more than 2-4 days and then getting failed without any error message or failure reason.

To debug the issue further, I have reran the playbook with setting verbose level to 3. In verbose level three, I could see only the following information is getting logged but no information about failure.

```
  ansible-playbook 2.7.0
  config file = /home/dbrun/.ansible.cfg 
  configured module search path = ['/home/dbrun/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules'] 
  ansible python module location = /home/dbrun/miniconda3/envs/dbrun/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible 
  executable location = /home/dbrun/miniconda3/envs/dbrun/bin/ansible-playbook 
  python version = 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 19:07:31) [GCC 7.3.0] 
Using /home/dbrun/.ansible.cfg as config file 
Parsed /home/dbrun/dbRunPlaybooks/4875-25/hosts/PROD/hosts inventory source with ini plugin 

**PLAYBOOK: RPCStart.yml ********************************************************* **
1 plays in /home/dbrun/dbRunPlaybooks/4875-25/Cognos/RPCStart.yml 

**PLAY [primary_host] ************************************************************** 
META: ran handlers 

**TASK [Start RPC process] ******************************************************* 
task path: /home/dbrun/dbRunPlaybooks/4875-25/Cognos/RPCStart.yml:13 
 ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: cog84 
 SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/dbrun/dbRunPlaybooks/4875-25/hosts/PROD/ssh_keys/dbrun_4875_25_prd"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=cog84 -o ConnectTimeout=100 -o ControlPath=/home/dbrun/.ansible/cp/ea2d6bf111 frasmhvpp11.de.db.com '/bin/ksh -c ". $HOME/.profile;cd /export/cognos/cognos/cognos_rpc;/usr/bin/nohup /export/cognos/cognos/cognos_rpc/run.sh > /dev/null 2 >&1 &"'
```

Following is the content from my playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: primary_host
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: cog84

  tasks:
      
    - name: Start RPC process
      raw: /bin/ksh -c  ". $HOME/.profile;cd /export/cognos/cognos/cognos_rpc;/usr/bin/nohup /export/cognos/cognos/cognos_rpc/run.sh > /dev/null 2 >&1 &"
      register: output_result
    - debug: var=output_result.stdout_lines
    
    - name: Date
      raw: date
      register: result
```

Any debugging pointer would be helpful.

Comment: What happens if you run the `ssh` command that is printed to your log directly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem is not with ansible. Problem is with the shell script which I am trying to run with the ansible playbook.